# Where can we use the scenario where we can create an anonymous class when we do it for an Interface?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

Interface :

```
public interface MyFirstInterface {
    void myFirstAbstractMethod();
    default void myDefaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hi I am default method in Interface.");
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class MyFirstClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFirstInterface myFirstInterface = new MyFirstInterface() {
        @Override
        public void myMethod() {
            System.out.println("Main class : "+this.getClass());
        }

    };

    myFirstInterface.myMethod();
    myFirstInterface.defaultMethod();

    }
}
```

Now we know we are instantiating a anonymous class, what I want to know is Why would anyone use it? What is the advantage or disadvantage of doing it?

Comment: Huh? What abstract constructor? I only see a method with return type `A`.

Comment: it is not a constructor, it is abstract method `a()` of type `A`. Constructors cannot be abstract.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no constructor for interface in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201489/there-is-no-constructor-for-interface-in-java)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "misread" by the asker.

Comment: Also, constructors don't have a return type.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a constructor. It is a method `a()` declaration with the return type `A`.

Also, we *can instantiate an interface* using an anonymous class. `Runnable` for example:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   @Override 
   public void run() { ... }
};

Runnable r = () -> { ... }
```